# Getting next page view from ViewPager when trying to autorefresh current page view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using `ViewPager` which contains `Fragment` which contains `RecyclerView`. There I am trying to auto-refresh only current(which is visible) page view every 10 seconds. But the problem is after 10 seconds `handler.postDelayed()` is updating view of the next page view (not which is visible). I know it's because `pager` loads 1 extra page and this is causing `holder` to update with that next `view` and `handler.postDelayed()` is updating that next `view` in `holder`.

How to solve this problem.

**here is my `autorefresh` method, I am calling it from `onBindViewHolder()`;**

```
private void startAutoRefresh(final ViewHolder holder, final String exchange,
            final int currentPosition, final int timer){
        new FetchData(holder, exchange, firstTimeLoadPosition).execute(
                Configuration.exchangesAPI.get(exchange));
        if (MainActivity.pagerPosition == currentPosition) {
            counterView.setText(timer + "");
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (timer > 0) {
                        counterView.setText(timer + "");
                        startAutoRefresh(holder, exchange, currentPosition, timer - 1);
                    } else {
                        Log.wtf("Reloading", currentPosition+"");
                        new FetchData(holder, exchange, currentPosition).execute(
                                Configuration.exchangesAPI.get(exchange));
                        startAutoRefresh(holder, exchange, MainActivity.pagerPosition, counter);
                    }
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Log your `MainActivity.pagerPosition` and `currentPosition`, is same or not.

Comment: yes its same i have Logged it. if it was not, method will not run again, it's running but updating the next view which is likely to visible on slide.

Answer (score 0):

use an interface and pass that interface as a parameter of the adapter... in the interface `interface GetPositionFromMainActivity extends Parcelable{int getPosition();}` and in MainActivity after setting adapter of view paper `GetPositionFromMainActivity getpos = new GetPositionFromMainActivity { @override getpos{ return viewpager.getPosition()}` and in recycler adapter `if(interface.getPos == currentPosition)` instead of a static variable.. I mean just use an interface instead of a static variable...
pass the interface to the adapter of viewpager ..and in the `getItem` of viewPagerAdapter pass the interface as `putParcelable` as bundle arguments.. get the arguments the fragment and pass the imterface to the recycler adapter...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onPageSelected` method of `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListenr` for this. For example,

```
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(final int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(final int position) {

        // It returns the position of currently visible page.
        // Write your code here, according to your slide position using switch or if else.
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
};
```

Comment: I thought of it but how do i get the `adapter` and `holder` in `onPageSelected()` and update `holder`. `ViewPager` containg `Fragment`, and `Fragment` contains `RecyclerView`. how do i get `holder` from this `recyclerView`.